# Spring jpa throws ClassCastException when using custom Query

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to get only specific set of columns from a query, however, I am getting ClassCastException.

```
2019-03-16 00:03:19.321 ERROR 8440 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.metadata.entity.FileItem] with root cause

java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to com.metadata.entity.FileItem
    at com.metadata.service.FileItemService.findFileWithVersion(FileItemService.java:39) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.metadata.service.FileItemService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$7a805cbb.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

Here are the very basics of my structure.

**FileItem**

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.IdClass;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@IdClass(FileItemId.class)
@Table(name = "files")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class FileItem {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Id
    private long version;

    @Column(name = "total_size")
    private long totalSize;

    private String name;
    private byte[] file;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Date createdAt;
}
```

**FileItemId.java**

```
import lombok.Data;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;

@Data
public class FileItemId implements Serializable {
    private UUID id;
    private Long version;
}
```

**FileItemRepository**

```
import com.metadata.entity.FileItem;
import com.metadata.entity.FileItemId;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface FileItemRepository extends JpaRepository<FileItem, UUID> {
    @Query("select f.id, f.version, f.name, f.totalSize, f.createdAt " +
            "from FileItem f " +
            "where f.id = ?1 and f.version = ?2")
    List<FileItem> findByFileIdAndVersion(UUID id, Long version);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.10.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#projections) in spring. However, I am not sure if it is the best solution.

**FileItemNoBlob**

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface FileItemNoBlob {
    UUID getId();
    Long getVersion();
    Date getCreatedAt();
    Long getTotalSize();
    String getName();
}
```

`FileItemNoBlob findByIdAndVersion(UUID id, Long version);` in repository seems working. It would be better to create another repository for projection classes as well to make it cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

It is a long time I didn't use JPA but it seems your query returns an array Object[]

Then the signature of your method should be :

```
@Query("select f.id, f.version, f.name, f.totalSize, f.createdAt " +
            "from FileItem f " +
            "where f.id = ?1 and f.version = ?2")
    Object[] findByFileIdAndVersion(UUID id, Long version);
```

Otherwise if you want to keep your method signature :

```
@Query("select f " +
            "from FileItem f " +
            "where f.id = ?1 and f.version = ?2")
    List<FileItem> findByFileIdAndVersion(UUID id, Long version);
```

Another solution :

```
@Query("select new com.mycompany.mypackage.MyDTO(f.id, f.version, f.name, f.totalSize, f.createdAt) " +
            "from FileItem f " +
            "where f.id = ?1 and f.version = ?2")
    MyDTO findByFileIdAndVersion(UUID id, Long version);
```

Where MyDTO is a custom java bean that you write for your needs.

Comment: Hi Nico. Thanks for the help. I am trying to get only get some columns so I guess the second one fill return with all columns. I will try the 3rd solution though